# MATPLOTLIB X-AXIS AND Y-AXIX tick background and font color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if is there a way to change the background color of the x-axis tick and y-axis tick background and font color.

For instance in the [example in this link](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_rgb.html), you can see that the x-axis(0,2,4,5..), and y-axis(12,10,8,6..) font color are black for the tickers. How can I change the background of the font to white, and the background to black as in the main figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have the functions you need (I only colored yaxis):

```
In [20]: f = figure(facecolor='red')
In [21]: ax = f.add_subplot(111)
In [22]: ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black')
In [23]: ya = ax.yaxis                  
In [24]: xa = ax.xaxis                           # you modify x ticks indepently
In [25]: ya.set_tick_params(labelcolor='green')  # label
In [26]: ya.set_tick_params(color='white')       # ticks
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It works, however when I do a savefig('')... It goes back to white. (In your case, the red goes back to white.) Does that happen to you as well if you save and then open the file?

Comment: I got it, just pass facecolor='black', to the savefig() func. Thanks ;)

Comment: Just one last question, in your code above you set do the following: ya.set_tick_params(color='white'), however the image you display the font color is still black?

Comment: @xd1 It is not black, y-axis ticks are white and letters are green but the green color is difficult to distinguish in the black background. The x-axis letters are black, also the ticks; you can see the difference. remember you should upvote the answer if you find it useful

Comment: @xd1 ah! yes when you save the outter part goes to white. To get the figure saved in the original color you must 'recolor' as you discovered. Great!